# Raspberry Pi LCD TFT not working

Tags: touchscreen, pitft

Well, I bought a Chinese LCD TFT touchscreen, 3.5 inches, but I cant get it working, because I cant find the drivers. The only thing it says in the back is www.mcufriend.com, but the page is not available. I tried following [this](http://diprofinfiniti.com/3-setting-lcd-module-pi-tft-3-6-inch-for-raspberry-pi-display-screen-mcufriend) tutorial, but the screen only appears white.

Comment: You can console yourself by knowing you haven't lost too much money.  There are dozens of similar looking but different screens.  You may be lucky and hit upon a tutorial for your screen, there again it may be quicker to buy a screen which is known to work on the Pi.

Comment: AFAIK your MCUFriend 3.5 inch is not compatible with the Pi 2.  Which model do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it, just by adding boot_delay=1 to config.txt

Comment: It would be helpful for other people who think they have an identical screen if you could post front and back photos and detail the instructions you followed (with any variations) to get your screen working.  It might save someone else a lot of time.  Which Pi models have you got the screen working on?

Comment: I have only tested it pn Raspberry pi B+ but maybe i could try with the 2B, ill do it later. But there is a odd thing, the rpi has to be connected to hdmi to work, otherwise the screen remains white.

Comment: All I can think of is that the HDMI is providing extra power, but that does not really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Forget it, my mistake, it can work even without hdmi output, and another thing i discovered is that the raspberry pi still outputs energy through its gpio ports after beign shutdown with sudo halt, so the screen preserves the last console lines

Comment: Photos on this link: http://s1298.photobucket.com/user/JacobSP/library/Raspberry%20Pi

Comment: Why not post one or two images here?